# R: matrix aggregation using data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, tapply

I would like to aggregate matrix E using dimnames of E. I can aggregate if E is matrix, but I don't know if E is data.frame. Please let me know how I can do the same thing using data.frame.

```
> E
   a1 a1 a2 a2
a1  1  5  9 13
a1  2  6 10 14
a2  3  7 11 15
a2  4  8 12 16

ef <- outer(colnames(E), row.names(E), paste)
ef
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
[1,] "a1 a1" "a1 a1" "a1 a2" "a1 a2"
[2,] "a1 a1" "a1 a1" "a1 a2" "a1 a2"
[3,] "a2 a1" "a2 a1" "a2 a2" "a2 a2"
[4,] "a2 a1" "a2 a1" "a2 a2" "a2 a2"

F <- matrix(c(tapply(E, ef, sum)), nrow=length(unique(row.names(E))), byrow=T)
> F
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   14   46
[2,]   22   54
```

Comment: data frames can't have duplicate row names.

Comment: Please provide an example of `E` as dataframe using `dput`.